# For loop does not work (and Visual Studio gives a warning), why?

Tags: c++

I isolated my code to the following test program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Begin" << '\n';
    for (unsigned int c = '\200'; c < 256; c++)
    {
        cout << c << '\n';
    }
    cout << "End";

    return 0;
}
```

And the for loop does not run, why?
I suspect it has to do with the char sizes, because it works up to `'\177'` and from `'\200'` it stops working. It seems like the character literals are treated as octal numbers, but why? And even if that is the case then `'\177'` is 127 and `'\200'` is 128 and both are still below 256?

The warning Visual Studio 2019 with the default C++ standard gives is:

> C6294: Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.

Disclaimer: This is based on actual code and I'm trying to understand what it is doing.

Comment: With Visual Studio you can add a `/J` option to make the `char` type unsigned. Then the warning goes away. But please don't do that for real code.

Comment: A `char` literal like `\200` has type `char`.   If `char` is a signed type 8-bit type, it cannot represent a value `\200`.    The resultant value you're using to initialise `c` is implementation-defined, but will typically be a value that a `char` CAN represent (e.g.  numeric value not exceeding `127`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the literals are in octal, but that does not matter. You would still have the problem with hex literals, too.

The real problem is that the literals are using the `char` type, which is *either* signed or unsigned by default, the C++ standard leaves it up to the compiler implementation to decide which to use (some compilers have options to let the user decide). A signed `char` has a max value of 127, so anything higher than that will **overflow** to a negative value, which you are then assigning to an `unsigned int`, thus yielding a very large value that is > 256.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, numerical escape sequences are mapped to some `char` type; '\200', with octal 200 = decimal 128 is above the typical maximum `char` value of 127, leading it to overflow. Assigning it then to an `unsigned int` causes it to wrap to some large number which is above 256; at this point, the warning comes in (since a fixed value above 256 is never below 256, the loop also doesn't run).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must look at the warning code.

[Reference Here for C6294 warning code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6294?view=msvc-170)

Your problem is when you declare this:

```
unsigned int c = '\200';
```

c give us 4294967168 as result.

So you for loop is not correct as microsoft says in the warning code.